# Codeigniter common templates

Tags: codeigniter

Let's say that I have a website that has 100 different pages.  Each page uses a common header and footer.  Inside the header is some dynamic content that comes from a database.

I'd like to avoid having to have code in every single controller and action that passes this common code into the view.

```
function index()
{
    // It sucks to have to include this on every controller action.
    data['title'] = "This is the index page";
    data['currentUserName'] = "John Smith";

    $this->load->view("main_view", data);
}

function comments()
{
    // It sucks to have to include this on every controller action.
    data['title'] = "Comment list";
    data['currentUserName'] = "John Smith";

    $this->load->view("comment_view", data);
}
```

I realize that I could refactor the code so that the common parts are in a single function and the function is called by the action.  Doing so would reduce SOME of the pain, but it still doesn't feel right since I'd still have to make a call to that function every time.

What's the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

One way I have been doing this is to extend the default controller class.  You can read up on extending classes with MY_Controller in the [user guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html). Inside this extended class you can include something that you ALWAYS want to do, like render the page header template before the main content, or authorise a users access etc.

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        //code to always do goes here
        echo 'Always print this comment';
        $this->load->view('partials/template_start');
    }
}
```

Then you can have your normal controller class extend THIS class by using

```
class MyControllerNameHere extends MY_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        //setup here
    }
    function index()
    {
        echo 'Only print this bit when this method is called';
        $this->load->view('partials/MYPAGENAMEHERE');
    }
}
```

There are other ways of doing this, I use a mixture of the above and [William's Concepts Codeigniter Template library](http://www.williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/).  Do a bit of searching - there are a few solutions for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation. I created an 'includes' folder, and in there put a file that had the repetitive code from my controllers. Then in the controllers just `include('/path/to/includeFile.php');`

Don't know if it's the "correct" way, but it works well for me.

Comment: NO. This is bad. Doesn't follow MVC and is generally bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this after a search of their site.  http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Header_and_footer_and_menu_on_every_page/  I'll review this page and its links, then post my thoughts.