# Separate header and footer with MVC Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I'm looking for a simple way to have the same header and footer displayed all the time whilst being able to switch out the main content area. I'm not sure how to achieve this with MVC.

Answer (score 11):

You could create a master view.

**views/master.php**

```
$this->load->view('header');
echo $content;
$this->load->view('footer');
```

And then create a base controller with a method to render the master view.  The content of the subview is loaded and passed to the master view.

**libraries/MY_Controller.php**

```
class MY_Controller extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function master_view($content_view, $data)
    {
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view($content_view, $data, true);
        $this->load->view('master', $data);
    }
}
```

Then extend this base controller and invoke the method of the base controller from your action methods.

**controllers/items.php**

```
class Items extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['items'] = $this->item_model->get_items();
        $this->master_view('items/index', $data);
    }
}
```

It tends to be more DRY than loading the header and footer in each view.

Comment: `items/index` is the index() function in the Items controller right?
I'm confused, this would be a recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a view for the header, and a view for the footer and spit them out at the top and bottom of each page. Or, create a template view and load it, then take other views and inject them into the content area of the template. Either way will get you where you want to be. If you want it to happen automatically, you can create the template view in the constructor of the controller and save it to a member of the controller class. Then use it such that say, $this->template will be the template view.

Comment: Are you saying I would have to add <?php $this->load->view('header')?> at the top of every view?

Comment: You could do it at the top of every major view, yes. But not EVERY view. However, I was saying at the top of every controller method.

Comment: If you are scratching your head and thinking WTF, that's wasteful!!! Then CONGRATS!! you've graduated from MVC university! MVC is designed to make a site maintainable, not easy to build. It intentionally takes longer to make everything.

Comment: Will adding this at the top of every view or at the start of every controller method put extra resource constraints on the server as the same header (including image) will be loaded over and over again or will this be cached by codeigniter?

Comment: If you turn on caching, it will be cached by CI. However, it WILL process that file every time it loads a NEW page, since each page counts as its own thing. I wouldn't worry, unless by 'header' you mean a crap-ton of side-bars and heavy-process things with database calls. At which point. Memcached to the rescue! Or rip out the heart of CI's cacher and use it on a case-by-case instance.

Comment: DampeS8N. Is not worrying about it really a good option. Although the header is only a simple image and two lines of dyamic text surely this will use alot of extra bandwidth over time.

Comment: The image will not, as the browser and ISP along the way will cache the image. That is out of CI's jurisdiction. The dynamic text will be downloaded for each page load anyway, regardless of caching. If you are worried about it, use memcached, which will let you store whole variables and string in memory. Then, you can 'tag' the header/footer in memcache, since it doesn't change, and it will load SUPER fast. But you'll still have to send it to the user.

Comment: This is worth talking about at greater length. Feel free to hunt me down and email me and I'll go over this at greater length with you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601159/codeigniter-common-templates/2601515#2601515 :)

Comment: That will certainly do it. But I pity the poor soul who comes along to maintain that code. lol

Answer (score 0):

Try Modular Seperation: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/121820/

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above, I do it like this:

```
$this->data['content']='your_content_view';
$this->load->vars($this->data);
$this->load->view('template');
```

Then in the template view:

```
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view($content);
$this->load->view('footer');
```

Views can load other views, so the template view loads a header view, then the view you specify in content, then the footer view.

Using this idea you can load sidebar views into the content, etc.